# How to get combobox selected item which is inside DataGridView in windows Application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to get the Combobox selected item which is inside a DataGridView?

Comment: Please provide a code sample with what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in the comments, it would be very useful to provide some sort of code example to explain what you're trying to achieve here, as our solutions may differ depending on the desired outcome, however, the standard procedure for retrieving information from a `DataGridView` is:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index
```

Or if you need the indiviual cell, then:

```
dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Index
```

If you're trying to get the string from the `ComboBox` then something along the lines of this may help you:

```
string SelectedText = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
```

You can then proceed to use the information however you please, for example, if you were trying to get the value instead of the string from the `ComboBox` then you would use `.Value` instead of using the `ToString()` conversions. This is where some information regarding what you're trying to achieve would come in handy.

Hope this helps